# Conditional statement not functioning properly

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Depending on the time of the day. I am trying to display Morning, Afternoon or Evening to the user using the JavaScript ( new Date() ) method. But what I am receiving in response is just the (else) statement. Can I get advice as to what I am doing incorrectly?

```
const mainHeader = document.getElementById("header");

var greetings = () => {
    var today = new Date();
}

window.onload= (e) => {
    greetings;


    if(today >= 1 && today < 12) {
        mainHeader.innerHTML = "<h3>Good Morning! And Welcome To Guess The Number</h3>"
        console.log("Morning: between 1 and 12");
    }  else if(today >= 12 && today < 17) {
            mainHeader.innerHTML = "<h3>Good Afternoon! And Welcome To Guess The Number</h3>"
            console.log("Afternoon: between 12 and 17");
    }  else if(today >= 17 && today <= 24) {
        mainHeader.innerHTML = "<h3>Good Evening! And Welcome To Guess The Number</h3>"
        console.log("Evening: between 17 and 24");
    }  else {
            mainHeader.innerHTML = "<h3>Welcome to Guess The Number</h3>"
            console.log("No time zone");
    }
}
```

Comment: `today` is a local variable in the `greetings` function, you can't access it in other functions.

Comment: You're also not calling the `greetings` function, you have to put `()` after the name.

Comment: Thinking a Date is an integer representing the current hour. Or that there’s a 24 involved—biggest hour is 23.

Comment: If you want the day of themonth, it should be `(new Date()).getDate()`

Comment: Unrelated, but “today” isn’t a great variable name for an hour.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the hour from `greetings()`, and then assign it to a variable in the `window.onload` function.

```js
const mainHeader = document.getElementById("header");

var greetings = () => {
  var today = new Date();
  return today.getHours();
}

window.onload = (e) => {
  var today = greetings()
  if (today >= 1 && today < 12) {
    mainHeader.innerHTML = "<h3>Good Morning! And Welcome To Guess The Number</h3>"
    console.log("Morning: between 1 and 12");
  } else if (today >= 12 && today < 17) {
    mainHeader.innerHTML = "<h3>Good Afternoon! And Welcome To Guess The Number</h3>"
    console.log("Afternoon: between 12 and 17");
  } else if (today >= 17 && today <= 24) {
    mainHeader.innerHTML = "<h3>Good Evening! And Welcome To Guess The Number</h3>"
    console.log("Evening: between 17 and 24");
  } else {
    mainHeader.innerHTML = "<h3>Welcome to Guess The Number</h3>"
    console.log("No time zone");
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You never define `today` in the onload function(even if you called greeting, today wouldn't be defined b/c var is function scoped). Instead replace `greetings;` with `var today = new Date().getHours();` and remove the greetings function.

If you still want to keep `greetings` as a function, you can replace it with `var greetings = ()=>new Date().getHours();` and replace `greetings;` with `var today= greeting();`

Comment: I made the update to where the var today = new Date() is within the onload function and I got the same results. The (else) statement is what displays.